# Set "Start With" value for Oracle sequence dynamically

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to create a release script that can be deployed on multiple databases, but where the data can be merged back together at a later date.  The obvious way to handle this is to set the sequence numbers for production data sufficiently high in subsequent deployments to prevent collisions.

The problem is in coming up with a release script that will accept the environment number and set the "Start With" value of the sequences appropriately.  Ideally, I'd like to use something like this:

```
ACCEPT EnvironNum PROMPT 'Enter the Environment Number:  '
--[more scripting]
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH &EnvironNum*100000;
--[more scripting]
```

This doesn't work because you can't evaluate a numeric expression in DDL.

Another option is to create the sequences using dynamic SQL via PL/SQL.

```
ACCEPT EnvironNum PROMPT 'Enter the Environment Number:  '
--[more scripting]
EXEC execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH ' || &EnvironNum*100000;
--[more scripting]
```

However, I'd prefer to avoid this solution as I generally try to avoid issuing DDL in PL/SQL.

Finally, the third option I've come up with is simply to accept the Start With value as a substitution variable, instead of the environment number.

Does anyone have a better thought on how to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the `COLUMN XX NEW_VALUE YY` syntax to perform calculation in SQL*Plus and store the result in a variable:

```
SQL> col sequence_num new_value seq
SQL> select &EnvironNum * 1000000 sequence_num from dual;
Enter value for environnum: 2
old   1: select &EnvironNum * 1000000 sequence_num from dual
new   1: select 2 * 1000000 sequence_num from dual

SEQUENCE_NUM
------------
     2000000

SQL> create sequence scott.seq1 start with &seq;
old   1: create sequence scott.seq1 start with &seq
new   1: create sequence scott.seq1 start with    2000000

Sequence created.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a reasonably limited number of databases you could start the sequences with a different values and then define an increment so that the sequence values do not collide. This would eliminate the expression in the start value.

So if you have 10 databases:

```
create sequence seq1 start with &startval increment by 10;
```

and startval is 1 for database 1, 2 for database 2, etc.

(This also eliminates the problem of sequences overlapping if the increment values grow into the next database's range)

Comment: +1: it works well although you will need to know the max number of environments

Comment: This is a clever solution and it would work for me (I'm not likely to have more than 10 instances).  However, I'm going to accept Vincent Malgrat's answer as it does a better job of actually accomplishing what I set out to do.

Comment: Might run into trouble if there's 11 databases. The increment amount could be changed of course...

Comment: right - you have to liberally estimate the number of databases up front, but if you don't care about large numbers for your surrogate keys then set the increment to 100 and you're probably covered.  I'm upvoting Vincent's answer as well, as it solves the exact problem posed by the original question.

Answer (score 1):

One trick I've used is to create an sqlplus script from the main script and then execute it:

maybe something like

```
ACCEPT EnvironNum PROMPT 'Enter the Environment Number:  '
spool seq_script.sql
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH '||&EnvironNum||'*100000;')
end;
spool off
@seq_script.sql
```

This should create a script file with `&EnvironNum` already evaluated (assuming user inputed '275', for example):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH 275*100000;
```